# How Can I Prevent MSSQL Injections in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms, sql-injection

I know this is a widely covered topic but after searching Google for MSSQL injection prevention for PHP, I have found close to nothing.

This is the closest ***[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** I could find, but it seems the answer is for `MySQL` and not `MSSQL`.

The PHP code I am using allows an admin to log-in to the website via form inputs in order to access the back-end. This code is what logs the admin in after the form has been submit:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$conn=mssql_connect('d','a','d');
mssql_select_db('d',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM back_end WHERE username='$username' AND
      password='$password'");
  if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = 1;
      $_SESSION['backname'] = $username;
    }
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {
    header("location:logingbm.php");
    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect log-in information!');</script>";
  } else {
    header("location:../d/index.php");
  }
?>
```

If somebody could give me a few hints towards what code I should put in to prevent malicious injections, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Step 1 - validate all user inputs before they make it to a query.  Step 2 - use query parameters.

Comment: SQL Injection or not, this code isn't escaping inputs even to prevent simple SQL errors where you might have a password containing a quote character

Comment: Also use `break;` after header redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the older `mssql` extension. It's no [longer available as of PHP 5.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php). Instead, there is now `sqlsrv` and that function set includes the ability to run [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php), which is the most secure way to run your queries.

Comment: Restrict passwords and usernames to [A-Za-z0-9], verify that they match before running the query (and immediately fail if they don't), and make a plan to switch to sqlsrv before this bites you elsewhere.